# c++: special behaviour for temporaries

Tags: c++, move, temporary

In the code below, why does the first call resolve to `catchClass(aClass&)` and given the temporary as a parameter in the second invoke `catchClass(const aClassCatcher&)`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class aClassCatcher{};

class aClass{
public:
    operator aClassCatcher(){
        return aClassCatcher();
    }
};

void catchClass(aClass&){
    cout << __FUNCSIG__ << endl;
}
void catchClass(const aClassCatcher&){
    cout << __FUNCSIG__ << endl;
}

int main()
{
    aClass aC;
    catchClass(aC); // calls catchClass(aClass&)

    catchClass(aClass()); // calls catchClass(const aClassCatcher&)

}
```

In case you are wondering where I came upon this, I am trying to understand move constructors as described in an article at [Dobb's.](http://www.drdobbs.com/move-constructors/184403855)

Comment: Because temporaries cannot bind to non-const lvalue references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, it is important to notice that the behavior you are observing is not related to move semantics, nor to the presence or absence of a move constructor. You could run your example on a C++03 compiler and observe the exact identical behavior.

The explanation for the behavior you are observing is that lvalue references to non-`const` (`aClass&`) can only bind to lvalues, while lvalue references to `const` (`const aClassCatcher&`) can bind both to lvalues and to rvalues (but do not allow modifying the object they are bound to, since they are references to `const`).

If you are working with Microsoft's VC compiler, that may sound strange to you. The reason is the MSVC has a non-Standard extension which allows binding rvalues to lvalue references to non-`const`. This is IMO a *bad* extension, and that's not how Standard C++ works.

Now this said, when you provide a temporary, which is an rvalue, the compiler has no chance but picking the overload that takes an lvalue reference to `const`. The overload taking an lvalue reference to non-`const` is simply not viable, because of what I previously wrote.

Now in your case, the second overload is viable because there is a user-defined conversion from `aClass` to `aClassCatcher`. That conversion will return a temporary of type `aClassCatcher`, and lvalue references to `const` can bind to temporaries. Therefore, your second overload is picked.

When you provide an lvalue, on the other hand, both overloads are viable, but the one accepting an lvalue reference to non-`const` is preferred because no conversion is needed.

Comment: hey... i just renamed aClass__ to aClassCatcher to avoid confusion... bit new around here... ill edit you answer for posterity... :-) thanks...

Comment: i get what you mean by the bad microsoft extension... cos, when i comment out `catchClass(const aClassCatcher&)` i get both calls resolving to `catchClass(aClass&)`

Comment: @user1055604: Indeed, and that's bad ;) I will edit the answer to match the edit to your question

Comment: the said non-standard extension is [C4239](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/186yxbac.aspx)... thanks for your answer...

Comment: just being sure, but in the second last statement of the second last para... do you mean `lvalue references to non-const can bind to temporaries. Therefore, your second overload is picked.` or is it `lvalue references to const`?

Comment: @user1055604: You're right, sorry about the confusion! Not sure why I wrote that, perhaps it was a wrong copy-paste

Comment: Given that the article was published in 2003, it's not surprising that it works with 2003 behaviour.

Comment: i realize that this behaviour has nothing to do with move constructors... but it is a key feature used in the implementation of them in the article... i found later today that this topic is best dissected in http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/